# Need to Find the Duration between PageLoad and Click for Next Page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I want to write a simple function which calculates the number of seconds a user spent on the page from the page loading to them clicking on the 'next' button. So, basically I need to know how much time a user spent on each page. Can anyone help me write this function in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your app.js file where your app is defined. To do this you need to inject $location and add a listener to '$locationChangeStart'. All that's left is just doing some math and logging.  I added the extra code to only log when a page was open for longer than .02.  Angular was doing some routing that was getting logging I beleive. So trial and error with the logging.
Doing it with this approach is cleaner in that you don't need to put it in all controllers.

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [.....]);
mainApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.currentPage = "";
    $rootScope.pageLoadedTime = "";

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {

        if ($rootScope.currentPage != "") {
            var seconds = (new Date().getTime() - $rootScope.pageLoadedTime.getTime()) / 1000;
            if (seconds > .02)
                console.log("Page: ", $rootScope.currentPage, " Seconds spent on page : ", seconds);
        }

        $rootScope.pageLoadedTime = new Date();
        $rootScope.currentPage = $location.url();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding event listeners:

```
document.addEventListener("blur", onBlur, false);
document.addEventListener("focus", onFocus, false);
```

Then create the onBlur and onFocus functions:

```
function onFocus() {
  $scope.blurTime= Date.now();
  log.debug('User time caught at ' + $scope.blurTime);
}

function onBlur() {
  var pageTime = Date.now() - $scope.pauseTime,
  log.debug('User continue - time is ' + pageTime + 'ms');
}
```

Do what you need to do within those functions. Warning: I did not test this out, so you'll ned to do some tweeking (check the events).